# ASP.NET Forms Based Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am looking for some guidelines regarding FORMS BASED AUTHENTICATION implemenation in my ASP.NET project

I have Welcome.ASPX page where Login Fields are displaying as follow

Welcome.aspx.vb

User Enter "LoginID" --> _LoginID.Text = "Test01"

User Enter "Password" --> _Password.Text = "Hello"

PersistForms.Checked

Click on Login button --> _btnLogin.Click

```
Protected Sub _Login_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles _Login.Click 

IF LoginID and Password MATCHES = TEUE THEN    // Comparison is done from database


FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(_LoginID.Text, PersistForms.Checked) 

 // Using above line it redirects to defailt webpage of my application BUT I WANT TO REDIRECT TO other then default page. How can i do this? ?? How to rediect to EmployeeInfo.ASPX page from here????


End Sub
```

Web Config is updated as follow

```
<authentication mode = "Forms">

<forms

loginUrl = "Login.aspx"

name = ".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />

</authentication>

<authorization>

<deny users = "?" />

</authorization>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't use Login control? it's powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DefaultUrl in your web.config. More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx

So you would do something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="welcome.aspx"
    defaultUrl="employeeInfo.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: will defaultUrl be used if ReturnUrl is in the querystring?  i.e. they've just been bounced out of a secured page

Answer (score 0):

Setup the cookie and do the redirect yourself: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513002246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.3.shtml

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie (_LoginID.Text, true)
Response.Cookies.Add (cookie)
Response.Redirect ("EmployeeInfo.ASPX")
```